# Fixing color to each path for donut in d3js

Tags: d3.js

I am drawing a donut in d3js. I had three values in the array dataset (e.g totalpop, ruralpop,urbanpop-----> [1000,2000,3000]).I want these values to fill with a specific color in donut (e.g totalpop - red color,ruralpop - blue, urbanpop-orange)

Below is what I have tried in the code

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
.domain([totalpop,ruralpop,urbanpop])
.range(["red","blue","orange"]); 

var dataset = [parseInt(totalpop),parseInt(ruralpop),parseInt(urbanpop)];


var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.innerRadius(r-20)
.outerRadius(r);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
.value(function(dataset){return dataset;});
```

The main code for color appending

```
var arcs = groupx.selectAll(".arc")
.data(pie(dataset))
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("class","arc");
```

Here I have added color to the path

```
arcs.append("path")
.attr("d",arc)
.attr("fill",function(dataset){return color(dataset.data)});
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for it? what's the value for 'totalpop', 'ruralpop', and 'urbanpop'?

Comment: I got solved below I have posted the answer thanks for your reply @huan feng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, here it goes, instead of adding at the end I have added color the the path when it is creating

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()                               
                    .domain(parseInt(totalwater),parseInt(ruralwater),parseInt(urbanwater))
                                                .range(["red","blue","orange"]);   
var arcs = groupx.selectAll(".arc")
                     .data(pie(dataset))
                     .enter()
                     .append("g")
                     .attr("class","arc")
                    .attr("fill",function(dataset,i){return color(i)})
arcs.append("path")
.attr("d",arc)
```